# Angularjs ng-select selected value not set

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am trying to populate a form to edit a user list.

**index.html:**

```
<h1>Users</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Role</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="u in users" data-ng-click="select(u)">
            <td>{{u.id}}</td>
            <td>{{u.username}}</td>
            <td>{{u.role.title}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<form>
    <label for="inputUsername">Username</label>
    <input data-ng-model="selectedUser.username" id="inputUsername" type="text">
    <select  data-ng-model="selectedUser.role"
             data-ng-options="r as r.title for r in roles"
             data-ng-change="">
    </select>
</form>

<pre>{{selectedUser |json}}</pre>
```

**controllers.js:**

```
angular.module('test-select')
        .controller('IndexCtrl',
        ['$scope', 'Restangular', function($scope, Restangular) {
                $scope.selectedUser = null;

                Restangular.all("roles").getList().then(function(roles) {
                    $scope.roles = roles;
                });
                Restangular.all("users").getList().then(function(users) {
                    $scope.users = users;
                });

                $scope.select = function(user) {
                    $scope.selectedUser = user;
                };
            }]);
```

What I want to achieve is, when I click on a row on the table I can edit the selected user in the form (to save the new values) Everything works fine, except for the users role. If I click on a row, the selected user role is not updated.

I think that has to do with the fact thaT the role list via Restangular call. Has anyone an Idea how I can solve this problem elegantly?

PS: I am using angular 1.2-rc2.

BR, Rene

Comment: Should not the ng-model for the `select` element be `selectedUser.role.title` ?

Comment: Unfortunately not working. See my solution bellow.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution works but I think it is not very elegant:

**index.html**:

```
<h1>Users</h1>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Role</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="u in users" data-ng-click="select(u)">
            <td>{{u.id}}</td>
            <td>{{u.username}}</td>
            <td>{{u.role.title}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<form>
    <label for="inputUsername">Username</label>
    <input data-ng-model="selectedUser.username" id="inputUsername" type="text">
    <select  data-ng-model="selectedUser.role.id"
             data-ng-options="r.id as r.title for r in roles"
             data-ng-change="update()">
    </select>
</form>
```

**controller.js**:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

angular.module('test-select')
        .controller('IndexCtrl',
        ['$scope', 'Restangular', '$resource', function($scope, Restangular, $resource) {
                $scope.selectedUser = null;

                Restangular.all("roles").getList().then(function(roles) {
                    $scope.roles = roles;
                });
                Restangular.all("users").getList().then(function(users) {
                    $scope.users = users;
                });



                $scope.select = function(user) {
                    $scope.selectedUser = user;
                };

                $scope.update = function() {
                     var role = _.find($scope.roles, function(role){
                         return role.id === $scope.selectedUser.role.id;
                     });
                     $scope.selectedUser.role.title = role.title;
                     $scope.selectedUser.role.bitMask = role.bitMask;
                }
            }]);
```